# Typescript import class

Tags: class, import, typescript

I have been trying to get this thing to work for quite a while now, and so far no solution that I have found has worked for me.

This is what I have:

```
//Test.ts
module t
{
    export class Test
    {
        constructor ()
        {
            alert("test");
        }
    }
}

//Main.ts
/// <reference path="Test.ts" />

var test: t.Test = new t.Test();
```

As you can see I have two files, one is Main.ts and the other one is Test.ts. They are both in the same folder. Also if it helps I am using VS2012 and the Typescript plugin.

Thank you for the help!
EDIT: Oh btw, I get the error (in chrome): Uncaught ReferenceError: t is not defined

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to include both scripts in your web page:

```
<script src="test.js"></script>
<script stc="main.js"></script>
```

Comment: Be sure that you put "test.js" before "main.js", otherwise you'll end up with the same error. I lost a girlfriend, a computer and my sanity because of not doing that (threw them all out in anger).

Comment: In the original question, it is `main.ts` that relies on `test.ts` - so they have to be this way around. You probably assumed that `test.ts` was testing `main.ts`, but that isn't the case in this question. I don't want you to lose another computer over this :)

Comment: Oh right. Fortunately I had the explained problem on another code base and just mixed it up here ;).