# How to use a huge typescript library without polluting html?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, typescript

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14294064/2136963) answer suggests to manually add reference to `.js` files produced by all used `.ts` files.

I intend to use a [library](https://github.com/jice-nospam/yendor.ts) with a complex structure. I already added top files to my html, but they have subreferences, which have subsubreferences and etc.

If `app.ts` starts with

```
/// <reference path="yendor/src/yendor/yendor.ts" />
/// <reference path="yendor/src/umbra/umbra.ts" />
/// <reference path="yendor/src/gizmo/gizmo.ts" />
/// <reference path="yendor/src/game/base.ts" />
/// <reference path="yendor/src/game/persistence.ts" />
/// <reference path="yendor/src/game/custom_events.ts" />
/// <reference path="yendor/src/game/actor.ts" />
/// <reference path="yendor/src/game/effects.ts" />
/// <reference path="yendor/src/game/item.ts" />
/// <reference path="yendor/src/game/creature.ts" />
/// <reference path="yendor/src/game/map.ts" />
/// <reference path="yendor/src/game/gui.ts" />
/// <reference path="yendor/src/game/engine.ts" />
```

Can I leave only

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Instead of

```
Whatever else is used by other libraies
<script src="yendor/src/yendor/yendor.js"></script>
<script src="yendor/src/umbra/umbra.js"></script>
<script src="yendor/src/gizmo/gizmo.js"></script>
<script src="yendor/src/game/base.js"></script>
<script src="yendor/src/game/persistence.js"></script>
<script src="yendor/src/game/custom_evenjs.js"></script>
<script src="yendor/src/game/actor.js"></script>
<script src="yendor/src/game/effecjs.js"></script>
<script src="yendor/src/game/item.js"></script>
<script src="yendor/src/game/creature.js"></script>
<script src="yendor/src/game/map.js"></script>
<script src="yendor/src/game/gui.js"></script>
<script src="yendor/src/game/engine.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="pixi.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

inside `index.html`?

I use visual studio 2015 to build this.

Comment: You can use bundle for this.

Comment: Do you mean module loader, like systemjs?

Comment: No, I mean concatenate all your js files for production. And use just one file for vendors (jquery, angular, rxjs...) and one for app (engine, gui, map...)

Comment: Is it possible to use this approach with visual studio?

Comment: It is. Thank you for idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option suggested by Miguel Lattuada, worked with specific library (yendor.ts), despite it used namespaces.

in Visual Studio 2015:

1)Open project settings

2)Go to TypeScript build tab

3)Set "Module System" to "None"

4)Mark "Output"->"Combine JavaScript output into file"

5)Specify **absolute** path to your app suffixed with `combined.js` For example, `C:\Users\admin\Google Drive\My App\Client\Client\combined.js`

6)Add reference to `combined.js` to your html file.

Comment: And you probably want to delete tests folder, since it executes instead of gmae sample without Jake

Answer (score 3):

You can do that by:

1. Organize your code using typescript [modules](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Modules.md)
2. Use module loader (systemjs or such) to load modules automatically

Following these two rules your index.html will look something like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="lib/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.src.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <script>
        System.defaultJSExtensions = true;
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) 
        {//Entry point of the application.
            System.import('app').catch(function(e)
            {
                console.error(e);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Without need to include every single file.

Comment: I would like to point out that this only works well with libraries designed to be exported in a modular manner. If the library itself isn't meant to be exported as a module it might not work. System.js can load it to be sure but nothing in your code can stop it from populating the window namespace if the library is set up to assign itself to window.

Comment: Is it possible to import modules, if modules themselves use only //<reference>? Will submodules be imported?

Comment: As far as I know - no, they will require you to add thouse as script tags. A bit on this topic you can read here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Namespaces%20and%20Modules.md

Comment: There is one more option I have not mentioned: you can create your own bundle concatenating all js files into one - and referring just to that one. That is in case if you have to deal with libraries written in non modular manner.

Comment: The author uses Jake. But the code as modules internally. If a code at "yendor.ts/src/umbra/umbra.ts" starts with `module Umbra` what should I write besides /// <reference path="yendor/src/umbra/umbra.ts" />?

Comment: `import Umbra = require("./yendor/src/umbra/umbra.ts");`
`import {Umbra} from "./yendor/src/umbra/umbra.ts";`
`import * from Umbra;` do not seem to work. The first two basically say, that "./yendor/src/umbra/umbra.ts" is not a module

Comment: If file starts with "module Umbra" - the code use namespaces (previously they were called internal modules) - and you have to include them as script tags.