# Using Typescript in the Browser

Tags: typescript, gulp, ecmascript-6, webpack, browserify

I have been struggling with this issue a lot lately. I am creating a new Typescript project, and I am trying to figure out the best way to use Typescript to connect with a database, and display the results in the browser. However, I am getting console errors in the browser as follows:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined ("export class Database")

Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined ("import {Database} from "./Database";")
```

From what I can tell, I am getting the error because the files are being transpiled to a CommonJS module which the browser cannot understand.

My question is: Is this the correct diagnosis of the issue? If so, what is the best way to resolve an issue like this?

One approach from my research says to use WebPack or Browserify, and others suggest using AMD/SystemJS or RequireJS. I am curious if this can be done with Gulp and Webpack, but I am not sure where to even start, or how that fits in the workflow.

Database Class

```
export class Database{
    //...
}
```

Mongo Class

```
<reference path="../../../typings/browser/ambient/node/index.d.ts" />
<reference path="../../../typings/browser/ambient/mongodb/index.d.ts" />

    import {IDatabase} from "../interfaces/IDatabase";
    import {Database} from "./Database";
    import {MongoClient} from "mongodb";

    class MongoDB extends Database implements IDatabase{
        //...
    }
```

Database Interface

```
export interface IDatabase{
    //...
}
```

TSConfig Options

```
"target": "es6",
"module": "commonjs",
"moduleResolution": "classic",
"sourceMap": true,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out my issue. I was referencing these files directly in the "index.html" page, which wasn't necessary. What needed to be done was change the reference so that the Node controller knew where the files were, and not the index page. After this, and on compile, the export and require worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some resources to get you started:

1. Webpack: [link](http://www.jbrantly.com/typescript-and-webpack/)
2. Gulp+webpack: [link](http://webpack.github.io/docs/usage-with-gulp.html)
3. Browserify: [link](http://www.davidkudera.com/2015/02/28/typescript-gulp-bower-browserify/)
4. Systemjs: [link](http://david-barreto.com/how-to-use-typescript-with-systemjs/), [link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#systemjs)
5. requirejs: [link](http://www.codebelt.com/typescript/typescript-amd-with-requirejs-tutorial/)
6. Sample gulp task: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35956888/gulp-and-ts-compilation/35957118#35957118)
7. Sample basic systemjs config in index.html: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35685702/how-to-use-a-huge-typescript-library-without-polluting-html/35685782#35685782)

There is no 'best way' it depends on the specifics of your application. If you need/can to bundle all app as a single js file - webpack or browserify. Otherwise - systemjs, maybe requirejs. My personal preference is gulp+systemjs. But as links 1-5 shows it can be done with any loader.

Browsers so far cannot load javascript modules and need so called loaders (that is webpack, requirejs, systemjs, browserify) to do the job. That is the reason why you see errors you specified. In order to get rid of them - choose one of the loaders, configure it and the errors will go away.

Hope this will help you to get started.

Comment: Hi Amid. Thank you for the links and information. It does provide helpful insight, however I am not sure that it answers the question on how to solve the issue of Uncaught Reference Error, or present an alternative diagnosis on what might cause it. I will look into how those tools can be used together though via your links.

Comment: I have updated answer. Sorry for not being clear about the reason for your errors.

Answer (score 0):

Now only the `tsc` command line tool can do all the things for you to use typescript on browser.

#### First of all, config the module to be 'AMD' in the tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "amd",
    "outDir": "./", //Just by default
    "rootDir": "./" //Just by default
  }
}
```

#### Secondly, prepare a really simple index html. It use the entry file index.js to boostrap the whole application(by require.js).

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="me">Nothing</div>

    <script data-main="./index.js" src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/require.js/2.3.6/require.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### Then, write whatever you want into the index.ts.

```
//import something from somewhere

const el : HTMLElement | null = document.getElementById('me');
if(el){
  el.innerHTML = 'Hey I am typescript!';
}
```

You can also import other files just like what you do in regular typescript.

#### Finally, run `tsc` command to compile all files then open the index.html, you can see what happens.